# VScode inserts a bracket ")" when pressing Ctrl+Enter in the editor

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Sometimes, when pressing `Ctrl+Enter` in VScode (Windows) to run a line of `R` code in the editor, it sends the code in the R terminal window and inserts a ")" at the end of the code and doesn't execute it.
I installed VScode as per the [online instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r). Most of the time I don't get that issue but sometimes I do (I beleive mostly when running a function with curly brackets `{}` ).

I inserted a screenshot for reference.
[image: VScode inserting a ")" when pressing Ctrl+Enter in Rscript]

Comment: It's hard to tell from this (and I don't use vscode), but often auto-paren-close is a feature many like, since it is a good indication of when you are "within" a paren-enclosure (whether you want to be or not).

Comment: It shouldn't add a closing bracket since there was no unmatched opened bracket in my code

Comment: there's no way for us to know that given a partial screenshot, so I gave a guess; good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the github issues for vscode-R. This is a Windows specific issue. There's a thread on this and the solution is not obvious/does not exist yet:
https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/820

Leaving the post here in case it might help people in the future